# Crash at Choreographer.java line 966

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Choreographer.java line 966
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

```
  androidx.recyclerview.widget.OrientationHelper$2.getDecoratedStart 
    (OrientationHelper.java:403)
    androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.getViewMin (GridLayoutManager.java:1159)
    androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager$2.getEdge (GridLayoutManager.java:1746)
    androidx.leanback.widget.Grid.removeInvisibleItemsAtEnd (Grid.java:416)
    androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.removeInvisibleViewsAtEnd 
    (GridLayoutManager.java:1840)
    androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.scrollDirectionPrimary 
   (GridLayoutManager.java:2473)
   androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy 
   (GridLayoutManager.java:2415)
   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.scrollStep (RecyclerView.java:1972)
   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run (RecyclerView.java:5476)
   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:966)
   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:790)
   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:721)
   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:951)
   android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I am getting this error and frequency of occurrence is less than 10%. Logcat description doesn't contains the classes used in the project. So, Is this bug related to the android code or it is because of our project code?

Comment: Before calling `getLayoutParams`, add a condition `if(yourView != null)`

Comment: The code is written in the Android inbuild class  OrientationHelper.java that is read-only.